# DO not match regex if it does not occur at the start of the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to write a regex for matching a sentence with exactly 3 words with one space between each word, with the middle word being "is".

For example, the regex should be a match if the input is

```
"This is good"
```

It should not be a match if the input string is

```
"This this is good"
```

This is what I am trying right now:

```
string text = "this is good";
string queryFormat = @"(?<pronoun>[A-Za-z0-9]+) is (?<adjective>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$";
Regex pattern = new Regex(queryFormat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = pattern.Match(text);

var pronoun = match.Groups["pronoun"].Value; //Should output "this"
var adjective = match.Groups["adjective"].Value; //should output "good"
```

The above regex matches the string "this this is good"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You probably do not want to match numbers. [A-Za-z0-9] should then be [A-Za-z]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?<pronoun>[A-Za-z0-9]+) is (?<adjective>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$
```

Jsut add the `^` start anchor to make it a strict match to 3 words and not a partial match.

```
^ assert position at start of a line
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/18

Comment: You should probably use something like `[\p{L}\p{N}]` or `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9]` to include unicode characters like accented letters.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You should probably put that comment on the question, not the answer, as the answers are jsut based on OP's code.

Comment: @Rawling you're right, it was actually a suggestion to improve the answer but I should have put that on the question instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the start of a line anchor ( `^` ).

```
string queryFormat = @"^(?<pronoun>[A-Za-z0-9]+) is (?<adjective>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$";
```